# coverage report showing zero

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

this code is saved with calc.py. This is a basic calculator program in which I have used flask module.

```
def sum(number1,number2):
    result= number1+number2
    return result

def sub(number1,number2):
    result= number1-number2
    return result
def mul(number1,number2):
    result= number1*number2
    return result

def div(number1,number2):
    result= number1/number2
    return result
```

This program is saved with testing.py name on my machine. the module used in this is unitest and calc from the above. I am doing testing here. since I am getting a 0% coverage report. please help me out. please comment on the links if possible.

```
import unittest
import calc

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sum1(self): # function to call self
#testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(10,15) #calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 1 of sum successful')

    def test_sum2(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(12,7)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,19)
        print('test 2 of sum successful')

    def test_sum3(self):       # function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,20)
        print('test 3 of sum successful')

    def test_sum4(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(12,8)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,20)
        print('test 4 of sum successful')

    def test_sum5(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 5 of sum successful')

    def test_sum6(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 6 of sum successful')

    def test_sum7(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 7 of sum successful')

    def test_sum8(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(12,7)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,19)
        print('test 8 of sum successful')

    def test_sum9(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 9  of sum successful')

    def test_sum10(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for addition
        result=calc.sum(12,7)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,19)
        print('test 10 of sum successful')

    def test_sub1(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(10,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,5)
        print('test 1 of sub successful')

    def test_sub2(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(12,7)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,5)
        print('test 2 of sub successful')

    def test_sub3(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,10)
        print('test 3 of sub successful')

    def test_sub4(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(12,8)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,4)
        print('test 4 of sub successful')

    def test_sub5(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,-5)
        print('test 5 of sub successful')

    def test_sub6(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(100,25)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,75)
        print('test 6 of sub successful')

    def test_sub7(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,10)
        print('test 7 of sub successful')

    def test_sub8(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(12,8)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,4)
        print('test 8 of sub successful')

    def test_sub9(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,-5)
        print('test 9 of sub successful')

    def test_sub10(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for substraction
        result=calc.sub(100,25)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,75)
        print('test 10 of sub successful')

    def test_mul1(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(2,4)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,8)
        print('test 1 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul2(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(6,2)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,12)
        print('test 2 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul3(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,75)
        print('test 3 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul4(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(12,8)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,96)
        print('test 4 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul5(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,150)
        print('test 5 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul6(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(5,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 6 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul7(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,75)
        print('test 7 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul8(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(12,8)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,96)
        print('test 8 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul9(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(10,15)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,150)
        print('test 9 of multiplication successful')

    def test_mul10(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for multiplication
        result=calc.mul(5,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,25)
        print('test 10 of multiplication successful')

    def test_div1(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(10,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,2)
        print('test 1 of division successful')

    def test_div2(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(12,6)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,2)
        print('test 2 of division successful')

    def test_div3(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,3)
        print('test 3 of division successful')

    def test_div4(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(12,3)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,4)
        print('test 4 of division successful')

    def test_div5(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(14,7)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,2)
        print('test 5 of division successful')

    def test_div6(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(100,25)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,4)
        print('test 6 of division successful')

    def test_div7(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(15,5)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,3)
        print('test 7 of division successful')

    def test_div8(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(12,3)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,4)
        print('test 8 of division successful')

    def test_div9(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(14,7)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,2)
        print('test 9 of division successful')

    def test_div10(self):# function to call self
        #testing is being done for division
        result=calc.div(100,25)#calculation module is being called
        self.assertEqual(result,4)
        print('test 10 of division successful')

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am getting a 0% coverage report, what to do??

Comment: How do you run the test?

Comment: Also, consider using `from operator import add, sub, mul, div` instead of baking your own

Comment: I was applying a simple code of   coverage module. and it was  "coverage report calc.py" on my machine

Comment: What happens if you take out the flask stuff?

Comment: nothing changed!!!   same 0%   coverage report

Comment: Interesting. Shouldn't you be running `testing.py` in your report, not `calc.py`?

Comment: coverage report testing.py
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------
testing.py     165    165     0%
--------------------------------
TOTAL          165    165     0%

Comment: still 0%,  can you please check if their any problem with my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236790/discussion-between-ritik-kumar-and-mad-physicist).

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote. Question seems legit, although I would add the command used to run the coverage and the console output to the question.

Comment: Also, please cut down the size of the test code in the MCVE. We only need to see the first of each test group, if even that many functions.

Answer (score 3):

In order to run the coverage using unittest simply run
`coverage run -m unittest discover`

and there is one unnecessary import you're importing

```
from flask import Flask,request,app
from flask import Flask,request
```

so change it to

```
from flask import Flask,request, app
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be because of coming straight to the `coverage report -m testing.py` command. Before this, try using command `coverage run testing.py` . This will run your testing file with coverage module.

Also i would recommend to use name **testing_calc.py** instead of only **testing.py**. This would help in easy accessibility of files in case of large project.

In addition, use different testing functions only when you want to test different functions. Like here you are using functions ***sum1,sum2,...,sum10*** to test only one function ***sum***. Try incorporating all the test cases for one function into one testing function. This will make your code free from redundant lines of code.

Hope I might be of some help :)